# Is there a spread operator in Java, or an equivalent?

Tags: java

In JavaScript, we can call a function using each item in an array as seperate arguments. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

```
// Using the spread operator
function myFunction(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction(...args);

// Using the .apply method
function myFunction(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction.apply(null, args);
```

Is there any equivalent in Java?

Comment: I would assume that Java would just use an overloaded method instead.

Comment: No, but if `myFunction` was declared to take a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter, then an array can be given instead, e.g. `void myFunction(int ... values)` can be called using `myFunction(0, 1, 2)` or `int[] args = {0, 1, 2}; myFunction(args)`.

Comment: Ahh yes, reflection. Nice find @hotzst. It's more cumbersome to write and you have to know the parameter types, but that'll do it for an `Object[]`, without special requirements for the method signature.